# I've made an email server using postfix and dovecot and I cannot send emails to Gmail! It works perfectly with Yahoo

Tags: server, email, postfix, mail, gmail

I've made an email server on Ubuntu 12.04 using postfix, dovecot and roundcube as an web interface. Sending and receiving mails from Yahoo works fine (well, to be honest with a delay of 5 minutes, I don't know why...), but when I'm trying to send an email to my gmail address, I get this error:

```
 I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                   The mail system

<xxxxxx@gmail.com>: host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4001:c0d::1a]
    said: 550-5.7.1 [2602:ff62:104:10c::] Our system has detected that this
    message does 550-5.7.1 not meet IPv6 sending guidelines regarding PTR
    records and 550-5.7.1 authentication. Please review 550-5.7.1
    https://support.google.com/mail/?p=ipv6_authentication_error for more 550
    5.7.1 information. 201si4583487ioc.208 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA
    command)
```

Can anyone give me some ideas? What I'm doing wrong? What about the delays that I'm encountering when sending and receiving from Yahoo!?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your e-mail server is trying to connect to gmail over IPv6. According to the error message, you have no [PTR record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types#Resource_records) for IPv6 pointing to your server.

If you can create PTR records yourself, you should do that. If you can't, you'll have to ask your server provider.

An example PTR record is this:

```
1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.8.b.d.0.1.0.0.2.ip6.arpa. 1h IN PTR host1.example.com.
```

Comment: Can you give me more info please? I mean, how can I do that?

Comment: Sometimes, your hoster allows you to create PTR records yourself, or you have your own DNS server. If so, you can add the records yourself. If not, you will have to ask your hoster to do it for you.